# Where do I install api code in podio and contact form 7?

Tags: api, contact-form-7, podio

Im trying to contact form 7 fields to fill podio fields when form is submitted. Where do I install api code in podio and contact form 7??

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Contact Form 7 within WordPress? You may need another plugin for [3rd party form integration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/forms-3rdparty-integration/), but you'll have to check on needed configurations.

Beyond that, you can install the [Podio PHP API](https://github.com/podio/podio-php) wherever your files will have access and include them in your PHP. (e.g. `require_once './podio-php/PodioAPI.php'`)